# CCSprite lags when moving it

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I'm developing a small game in Cocos2d and have some problems with CCSprite lags.

That's beginning of the game level:

[image]

And lags:
[image]

Lags happens when image with seabed have moved.

All graphics I take from CCSpriteBatchNode...
Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: pretty pics, however they dont say much. What lag (seen or measured?), on device or simulator ? size of the texture, number of sprites, etc etc etc.

Comment: On device and simulator.
About 32 sprites.
Seabed size 640x1136

Comment: You are moving the background? If not, why did you have the seabed with that size?

Comment: I have 3 background images: bottom of the level, top of the level and water.
in my game I'm moving top and bottom...

Comment: Ok, but you need the bottom to be the same size as the entire screen? Because that could be the problem...moving big images could be a bad idea...

Comment: Ok... Can you give me an advice how to solve this problem?